# TYPO3 : Adding plugin to page using the code

Tags: typo3

As a beginner with TYPO3 CMS in a new job, I had to make a new extension with differents plugins with a new table called "Products" and make the migration between the old products system and the newest one.

The goal of this was to adding automatically my plugin into the webpages using the code (no other solution, literally too much page to adding my plugin by hand).

I tried adding the reference of my plugin in the `list_type` field in my `tt_content` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

My question is: "Which fields I have to fill in in order to adding my plugin into my page?"

Comment: I think you went through this guide? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/Index.html

Comment: Yes I basically went through but I didn't find any informations on how about to adding it via code. To specify I already tested my plugins added by hand in a page and it work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been following [common plugin registration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/7-Controllers/2-Configuring-and-embedding-Frontend-Plugins.html) your plugins will be in `tt_content` with `CType: list` and `list_type: <extensionkey>_<pluginkey>` (without any other underscores - for the linked example that would be `exampleextension_list`).

Some Background: TYPO3 (or rather TypoScript CONTENT, the base of all rendered content) then draws the rendering configuration from TypoScript setup in `tt_content.list.20.<list_type>`. In your case that will hold an entry point to render an Extbase action.

Required fields for your plugin in `tt_content`: `pid`, `colPos`, `CType`, `list_type`. If you used a Flexform for the plugin settings, also `pi_flexform`.

If you need something else, it is easiest to find out by adding your plugin via the backend and inspect the newly added DB record in `tt_content` afterwards.

Hints for debugging (I assume TYPO3 v9+):

- Set TYPO3's application context to 'Development' by [setting the environment variable TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Bootstrapping/Index.html#application-context) - this will show you the tt_content column names in the backend forms.
- Set FE/debug = 1 (in LocalConfiguration.php or via InstallTool/Settings/Global Configuration) - this will show warnings in the frontend if your plugin configuration could not be found.

Comment: This helped me a lot to understand how it work and solved my problem, thank you !